# Could we define derivatives from the Taylor expansion?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Would it be equivalent to the usual definition if we defined the derivative $Df$ of a function $f: \text{I} \subseteq R \to \Bbb R$, where $\text{I}$ is some open interval in $\Bbb R$, as the function $g: \text{I} \subseteq \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=f(x_0) + g(x_0)(x-x_0)+O(x^2)$ for all $x,x_0 \in \text{I}$?  That is, I'm wondering if we can presuppose Taylor's theorem and then define the derivative, and (via the obvious extension of this) higher order derivatives, in terms of the Taylor expansion.

If this is equivalent, is there some text (textbook or paper) using this definition?  If it's not, why isn't it?

Comment: Using $O(x^2)$ is a stronger requirement than $o(x)$, the latter being exactly equivalent to the usual definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You meant $O((x-x_0)^2)$. If $f$ is differentiable and $g=f'$ then $f$ and $g$ need not satisfy $f(x)=f(x_0)+g(x_0)(x-x_0)+O((x-x_0)^2)$ (that will hold under stronger conditions on $f$.)

But if $f:I\to\Bbb R$ then yes, $f$ is differentiable if and only if there exists a function $g$ with $$f(x)=f(x_0)+g(x_0)(x-x_0)+o(x-x_0)\quad(x\to x_0)$$(where the convergence is not uniform in $x_0$.) This is just algebraic manipulation of the definition: Saying $f'(x_0)=g(x_0)$ says $$\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-g(x_0)=o(1)\quad(x\to x_0),$$which is the same as $$f(x)-f(x_0)-g(x_0)(x-x_0)=o(x-x_0)\quad(x\to x_0).$$